# What is the size of the Perfect binary tree with n nodes in last level

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees

I want to know how to calculate total number of nodes in a perfect balanced binary tree with $n$ nodes in the last level. I know the answer is $2\cdot 2^{\log n} - 1$. Just curious how this can be calculated

Comment: Have you tried to draw such a tree?  Try drawing all such trees of depth up to 5.  Is there a relation between the number of _internal_ nodes and the number of _leaves_?  The leaves are the nodes on the lowest level, the internal nodes are all the rest.  Just count them and see how it looks.  You will find out $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i$ vs. $2^n$.

Answer (score 5):

A perfect (binary) tree of depth $k$ has exactly $2^{k+1}−1$ nodes.

There are probably several ways to prove it. A simple way is by induction.
Each level has twice as many nodes as the previous level (since each node has exactly 2 children in a binary tree). The base level - the root - has 1 nodes. Note that the root is depth 0, not 1.

Let's denote the number of nodes in level $i$ by $N_i$. We know,

$N_0 =1$
$N_i = 2N_{i-1} = 2^{i}$

The total amount of nodes (of tree of depth $k$) is $S_k \equiv N_1 + N_2 + \cdots + N_k$, that is,

$$ S_k = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + \ldots +2^{k}.$$
This is a geometric series, whose sum is $S_k = 2^{k+1}-1$.

Now for your question:
We are given a perfect (binary) tree with $n$ nodes *at the last level*, how many nodes does it have overall?
We are given that at the last level (call it level $k$) we have $N_k=2^k=n$ nodes. Then $k=\log_2 n$ and we get that $S_k=2^{k+1}-1=2n-1$; Yes, each level has one more node than the entire tree above it.

A related question:
we are given a perfect (binary) tree with $n$ nodes, what is its depth?
Now we are given that the total number of nodes is $S_k = 2^{k+1}-1 = n$, thus $k=\log_2 (n+1)-1$ (again, the root is considered depth 0 here).

Comment: `Yes, each level has one more node than the entire tree above it.`. Does it mean that the amount of nodes in the last level of a binary tree linearly dependent on the total amount of nodes in the tree(in case the binary tree is balanced)?

Comment: Can this work for any arity tree? Say I have a 3-arity tree where every interior node has 3 children. Would there be 3^(k+1)-1 nodes?

Comment: @Breedly, let's repeat the argument. Number of nodes in Level 0: $N_0=1$. Level 1: $N_1=3$.... Level i:  $N_i=3^i$ nodes.  Total number of nodes up to depth $k$: $N_0+N_1+...+N_k$. This sum gives $\frac{1}{2}(3^{n+1}-1)$ (try in wolfram alpha for instance).

Comment: In general, for $q$-ary trees, the sum of the geometric series is  $1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^k = \frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}$.